# Over the internet what happens to requests when server is at maximum capacity

Tags: http, tcp, webserver, client-server

In a typical view of the internet you have a client that makes a HTTP request. This hits a server which processes the request and returns back to the client a response. I'm confused to what happens though if multiple clients make the same HTTP request to the same server at the same time.

I think a typical server can handle multiple requests at the same time so if the amount is less than that then there is not a problem. If it is more though then what happens exactly? Searching online I can't find an answer but I would think it is one of the following but maybe I'm entirely wrong:

1) If the server is already at full capacity then making a request just does not get a response

2) There is a queue somewhere which keeps idle requests until the server is ready to process them. This queue would be on the server itself or somewhere else?

3) Is this something handled by the TCP protocol, if it does not make the connection straight away because the server is overworked it tries again after a time limit

Comment: If an HTTP server is at full capacity, then either the TCP connection will simply fail to connect, or if the connection is successful (maybe it already established, ie from an earlier HTTP keep-alive) then the server can simply decide to fail the request with an error code like `503 Service Unavailable` or similar. Or, the server may not respond at all, and the client can decide whether to wait or timeout on its end.  TCP has no concept of HTTP, so this is strictly between the server and client to handle on their respective ends.

Comment: In these 2 cases then: 1) If the TCP connection fails does it automatically try to make a new connection or is the client responsible for resending the request. 2) Rather than sending 503 Service Unavailable is there any reason it can't keep it add these requests to a queue to handle later?

Comment: "*If the TCP connection fails does it automatically try to make a new connection or is the client responsible for resending the request*" - that is the client's responsibility, TCP will never retry a connection automatically, it will simply fail. "*Rather than sending 503 Service Unavailable is there any reason it can't keep it add these requests to a queue to handle later?*" - that is entirely up to the server to decide. But if a client has to wait too long for a response, it may just give up waiting, close the connection, and move on.